# How to have a singleton class and use it through out the application c#

Tags: c#, json, serialization, singleton, global

I have a class which deserializes a JSON file.
The JSON is styleconfig.json

```
    {  
        "Style1": {  
            "Font":       "Arial",   
            "width":      "25px",   
            "className":    "Grid-side"
        }  ,
"Style2": {  
            "Font":       "Arial",   
            "width":      "25px",   
            "className":    "Grid-side"
        }  
    }
```

I have a classA:

```
 var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
Dictionary<string, string> sData = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
```

So I need to call this classA every time in my application
For Example
There are two pages...Page1 and page2 both the style variables are there on json
so every time I need to call the classA to Deserialize

1. page1 call classA to Deserialize
2. page2 call classA to Deserialize

So this may affect the performance.End of the day the JSON file is the same for the whole application

So my requirement is to run classA only once when I login into the application and make the
Deserialized JSON object throughout the application.
I need some help with this

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with a static class and use a Lazy<> to ensure it is loaded only once:

```
public static class A
{
    private static Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>> _data = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>(() => GetData());

    public static Dictionary<string, string> Data => _data.Value;

    private static Dictionary<string, string> GetData()
    {
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        return jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use [Lazy<T>](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.lazy-1?view=net-5.0) for that. Here's an example:

```
static class ClassA 
{
    private static Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>> _json = new Lazy<Dictionary<string, string>>(ReadJson);

    private static Dictionary<string, string> ReadJson()
    {
        var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
        return jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
    }

    public Dictionary<string, string> Json => _json.Value;

}
```

Now the first time you read `ClassA.Json` the file will be parsed and read. The subsequent calls will just return the cached value.

Comment: In this, i have a method ReadJson() with parameter for example Readjson(int a).So iam unable to use the above .And thank you so for your reply was really helpfull. @torvin

Answer (score 0):

If I have correctly understood your question, apart from a lazy field already explained in other comments, have you tried a simple property?

```cs
 public class ClassA
    {
        //Just a singleton model
        static ClassA _SingleInstance = null;
        public static ClassA SingleInstance
        {
            get
            {
                if (_SingleInstance == null)
                    _SingleInstance = new ClassA();

                return _SingleInstance;
            }
        }

        Dictionary<string, string> _Data = null;
        public Dictionary<string, string> Data
        {
            get
            {
                if (_Data == null)
                    LoadData();
                return _Data;
            }
        }

      
        private ClassA()
        {
            //your constructor
        }
        
        //As pointed out by torvin, to avoid multithread races, load must
        //be synchronized
        private void LoadData()
        {
            lock(LoadMutex)
            {
                if (_Data == null)
                {
                    var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                    string json = new StreamReader(context.Request.InputStream).ReadToEnd();
                    _Data = jss.Deserialize<Dictionary<string, string>>(json);
                }
            }
        }

        private static readonly object LoadMutex = new object();

    }
```

and then from Page1 and Page2, you call it:

```cs
    Dictionary<string, string> myConfigData = ClassA.SingleInstance.Data;
```

Comment: The disadvantage of using "simple property" vs using `Lazy` is that it's not thread safe and it can call `LoadData` twice which might be undesirable

Comment: you are totally right, it should use some mutex synchrornization. I edit my answer

Comment: no, you should use `Lazy<>` which is specifically made for this use case